# Exporting DXF from QGIS projection?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, autocad, dxf

I'm working on exporting a shapefile of contour lines as a DXF file so that  my colleague can use it in autoCAD. When they try to add the DXF file it doesn't keep the projection (NAD83 UTM zone 20) I assigned it when I exported it. I've tried using different projections and different methods to export the DXF (I've done the right click on the layer and "save-as" autoCAD, and I've done file > export as DXF). I'm using QGIS v 2.18.10 and I'm not sure which version of cad my colleague is using but I'm assuming it's a recent version.

Comment: College or colleague?